# Product of lists of lists with variable members

Tags: python, list, membership

Say I have this input data

```
my_input_list = [[A],[A,B,C],[D],[D,E,F],[A,B,C,D,E,F],[A,C,E]]
items_that_appear_twice = [A,B,C]
items_that_appear_four = [D,E,F]
```

And I want to create an expansion such that some elements are only allowed to appear twice.

```
my_output_list = [
[A],[A],
[A,B,C],[A,B,C],
[D],[D],[D],[D],
[D,E,F],[D,E,F],[D,E,F],[D,E,F],
[A,B,C,D,E,F],[A,B,C,D,E,F],[D,E,F],[D,E,F],
[A,C,E],[A,C,E],[E],[E]]
```

I tired a few ideas and didn't find a really neat solution, like building lists of four and `list.remove()` from them which generated two empty lists.
For example list removal techniques on `my_input_list[0]*4` gives `[A],[A],[],[]` (two empty lists) when I want `[A],[A]` .

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I really can't make sense of your mapping from input to output.

Comment: where does the last 2 elements `[E],[E]` come from? Ó_ò Same question with `[D,E,F],[D,E,F]` elements which are after `[A,B,C,D,E,F],[A,B,C,D,E,F]`

Comment: I think I understood... they are the elements that are allowed to apear four times. See answer :)

Comment: Yeah the last two are the tricky ones.  you get 4 of the items_that_appear_four but only 2 of the items_that_appear_twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working version: [See Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/524bde82-6c42-49b2-84a6-b64dac3d563f).

```
my_input_list = [['A'],['A','B','C'],['D'],['D','E','F'],['A','B','C','D','E','F'],['A','C','E']]
items_that_appear_twice = ['A','B','C']
items_that_appear_four = ['D','E','F']

my_output_list = []
for my_input in my_input_list:
    items_allowed_to_appear_twice = list(filter(
        lambda value: (value in items_that_appear_twice 
                       or value in items_that_appear_four),
        my_input))

    items_allowed_to_appear_four = list(filter(
        lambda value: value in items_that_appear_four,
        my_input))

    my_output_list += 2*[items_allowed_to_appear_twice]
    if len(items_allowed_to_appear_four):
        my_output_list += 2*[items_allowed_to_appear_four]

print(my_output_list)
```

Comment: Marked as answer but thanks to everyone for all the fine choices.  Hard to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_input_list = [['A'],
                 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                 ['D'],
                 ['D', 'E', 'F'],
                 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                 ['A', 'C', 'E']]
items_that_appear_twice = ['A', 'B', 'C']
items_that_appear_four = ['D', 'E', 'F']

my_output_list = []
for sub in my_input_list:
    my_output_list.append(sub)
    my_output_list.append(sub)
    sub = [x for x in sub if x in items_that_appear_four]
    if sub:
        my_output_list.append(sub)
        my_output_list.append(sub)

assert my_output_list == [
    ['A'], ['A'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D'], ['D'], ['D'], ['D'],
    ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['A', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'E'], ['E'], ['E']]
```

Comment: Small improvement, you can replace the two `my_output_list.append(sub)` with just one `my_output_list += 2*[sub]`, in both occurences. [Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/48d007c0-c96d-4a57-a37b-5807d44a5b8e)

Comment: @raul.vila that's clever, shorter, and more flexible if OP changes the numbers, but for now I prefer my version because it's instantly obvious what it does, whereas I had to think for a moment to understand yours.

Comment: No need to change your code, of course. With your version and my comment anyone can choose :).

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution, sort the sub list first, then append to the result according different situation.

```
my_input_list = [['A'],['A','B','C'],['D'],['D','E','F'],['A','B','C','D','E','F'],['A','C','E']]
items_that_appear_twice = ['A','B','C']
items_that_appear_four = ['D','E','F']

result = []
for sublist in my_input_list:
    appearence = {1:[], 2:[], 4:[]}
    for item in sublist:
        appearence[2].append(item) if item in items_that_appear_twice else (appearence[4].append(item) if item in items_that_appear_four else appearence[1].append(item))
    if len(appearence[2]) > 0:
        result.append([appearence[2] + appearence[4]] * 2 + ([appearence[4]] * 2 if appearence[4] and len(appearence[4]) > 0 else []))
    else:
        result.append([appearence[4]] * 4)
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

output:

```
[['A'], ['A']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
[['D'], ['D'], ['D'], ['D']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'E'], ['E'], ['E']]
[Finished in 0.178s]
```